# Oracle how to find rows containg some value in json array column

Tags: arrays, json, oracle

Oracle I want to filter rows from table where json array column view_role has value 1. Solution may be only in where clause or using join as well. I have spent 3 days for this solution please suggest me what i am doing wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE test_fields
(
   field_id      NUMBER  NOT NULL,
     field_name VARCHAR2(100),
   view_role     VARCHAR2(1000) CHECK (view_role IS JSON)
);


INSERT INTO test_fields VALUES(1, 'StaffName', '[1,10,50,100]');
INSERT INTO test_fields VALUES(2, 'Salary', '[50,100]');
INSERT INTO test_fields VALUES(2, 'Email', '[10,50,100]');
commit;

SELECT * FROM TEST_FIELDS;

        


-- I want to find fields for role 1;
    
SELECT f.field_id, f.field_name
       jt.role
  FROM TEST_FIELDS f,
       json_table(f.view_role[*]
         COLUMNS ("ROLE" VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$')) jt
 WHERE jt.role = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of `JSON_TABLE` is incorrect. The first argument is the JSON Value to convert to a table, and the second argument is definition of the JSON selectors to find the information you need.

This query should give you what you're looking for:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM test_fields, JSON_TABLE (view_role, '$[*]' COLUMNS (role NUMBER PATH '$')) jt
 WHERE jt.role = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ej Egyed It solved my problem. I have one more request can you please share me where condition without joing JSON_TABLE may be using Json_exists

Comment: It's not possible to look for a specific value in a JSON array using JSON_EXISTS, but you can use regex if you'd like with a query like this `SELECT * FROM test_fields WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (view_role, '\D1\D')`

Comment: Ok thank you for your solution and quick response. Its also useful in my use cases